# Fetch and sort mixed character from firebase javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Structure

```
Periods
 +Period1
 +Period10
 +Period2
 +Period3
 +Period4
```

I am getting the value as it is. But i want to be sorted like `Period1, Period2, Period3..,Period10`

Answer (score 0):

Referring to :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order

When using orderByKey() to sort your data, data is returned in ascending order by key.

Children with a key that can be parsed as a 32-bit integer come first, sorted in ascending order.
Children with a string value as their key come next, sorted lexicographically in ascending order.

You could avoid the "Period" as a redundancy as it is implied from the table and use the numeric id directly (not recommended by firebase) or use the push to generate the keys (ids) native to firebase.

Comment: any other option in javascrpt?

Comment: you sort after you receive or use correct keys in advance (recommended) to enable further query options

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Database sorts strings lexicographically. And in alphabetical order `Period10` comes before `Period2`.

To ensure the lexicographical order also matches the numerical order that you're looking for, you can consider padding the numbers:

```
Periods
 +Period001
 +Period010
 +Period002
 +Period003
 +Period004
```

With this padding, the lexicographical order matches the numerical ordering that you're looking for. Of course the amount of padding will depend on the maximum number you realistically expect.

Alternatively you can simply store a `Period` property with a **numeric** value in each child node and order on that. In that case you can also use push IDs for the keys, as Alex said:

```
Periods: {
  -Laaaaaa: {
    Period: 1
  },
  -Laaaaab: {
    Period: 10
  },
  -Laaaaac: {
    Period: 2
  },
  -Laaaaad: {
    Period: 3
  },
  -Laaaaae: {
    Period: 4
  }
}
```

Now you can query `ref.orderByChild("Period")` and the children will be returned in the wanted numerical order.

Comment: van i cannot change the database structure, is other any other in javascript?

Comment: No. If you want the ability to order the data numerically, you'll need to store it in a format that allows that.